# How get unlimited "free" Flint, aka a Flint farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing Minecraft Feed the Beast Infinity Evolved mod, on a towny + lwc protected server, and i need to get unlimited flint, for my sagmils.

I'm unable to do this:

because block placer don't work inside towny...

I already tested outside towny and it Works there...

but I need a towny compatible solution.

Any ideas how can I get unlimited flint?

EDIT:

The server have infinite amounts of lava, water, and cobblestone, on public tesseracts.
And I only need a way to convert gravel into flint instead of placing it and digging it every time... i need like thousands of flints...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grinding cobblestone in a Thermal Expansion pulverizer has a chance of dropping a gravel block, which can then be run through another pulverizer to get flint. You can hook one up to an infinite cobble generator using lava, water, and some sort of mining machine.

Keep in mind this is going to churn out a fantastic amount of sand as a side effect (which might or might not be useful), and won't be particularly fast (the gravel drop is a chance, not guaranteed).

Mekanism's crusher does have a straight cobblestone->gravel recipe, but I don't think it's included in FTB Infinity Evolved.

Comment: i guess for gravel i can pulverize netherrack... but how automate flint from gravel?

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva Gravel run through a pulverizer gives flint, added it to the answer.